# In python, how do you launch an Amazon EC2 instance from within a Google App Engine app?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, amazon-ec2

In python, what is the best way to launch an Amazon EC2 instance from within a Google App Engine app? I would like to keep my AWS keys as secure as possible and be able to retrieve the public DNS for the newly launched EC2 instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you can use [boto](http://code.google.com/p/boto/) with the current App Engine release (and maybe [AEP](http://code.google.com/p/app-engine-patch/) to help, though maybe that's not needed for your specific task of starting an instance and retrieving its public domain name).  [This post](http://blog.localkinegrinds.com/2009/04/02/lessons-learned-google-app-engine-app-engine-patch-django-boto/) has a good overview of "lessons learned" while getting all this to work. (Sorry, no personal experience -- my occasional playing with AWS has been done from my laptop, disconnected with my more intense use of GAE;-).

If this doesn't work for you or doesn't meet you needs, perhaps you could give us details of what you tried, how it failed, and what different behavior(s) you're looking for...?