# Running Boto on Google App Engine (GAE)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, amazon-ec2, boto

I'm new to Python and was hoping for help on how to 'import boto.ec2' on a GAE Python application to control Amazon EC2 instances. I'm using PyDev/Eclipse and have installed boto on my Mac, but using simply 'import boto' does not work (I get: : No module named boto.ec2). I've read that boto is supported on GAE but I haven't been able to find instructions anywhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't copied the boto code to the root of your app engine directory.

Boto works with GAE but Google doesn't supply you with the code.  Once you copy it into the root of your GAE directory, the dev server should work, and after your next upload it will work on the prod server as well.

Comment: This worked. I copied the contents of the "boto/boto" directory into my project's root folder (/MyProject/boto). In order to get the Python unit-test's without hiccups I also had to remove a couple of files/folders that were causing issues (boto/core, boto/manage/cmdshell.py, boto/manage/test_manage.py and boto/mashups/order.py). Maybe there was another way to run the unit tests (using PyDev) without having to touch anything in the boto library? Finally, I had follow these steps in to get rid of the SSL errors: [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/boto-users/lzOKsZFKTM8)

Comment: I run `nose` from the command line and I specify my own test directory in the arguments so it doesn't run the `boto` tests.

Answer (score 3):

Symbolic link should be enough.
in your project root:

```
ln -s /path/to/boto/boto boto
```

Google app engine will upload it while deploying your app.

Comment: I do that too.  Makes maintenance easier.